# Is there Biology Careers like Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm quite a new user here on StackExchange. I just got an invitation the other day to Stack Overflow Careers and I was wondering if is there something similar for Biology as well? If there isn't, are there plans for it? It would be nice to have something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer no there isn't a Bio careers. You can see from the drop down menu. Here is Bios

[image]

and here is SO

[image]

Will there every be a Bio careers? I can't say but I would think not. I say this because it is much easier to get a feel for a programmer from viewing their SO careers page which has a link to their SO account. Additionally, with programming careers, firms may want someone with a degree in computer science but they would hire someone with a HS diploma if they are a superior programmer compared to the candidate with the newly minted degree and pay them the same or more. In Bio, you cant take the risk of hiring an amateur biologist who does this for interest or fun even if they have the knowledge of someone with a PhD. This seems unfair but that is how it works with pretty much every profession except for programming. One example is the NSA, they want BS, MS, and PhD but if you have a HS diploma and serious talent you can get a job.

Comment: There will be some day when there will be such a site. Moreover to be a bio-professional you need a lab experience. For programming one can get that experience sitting at home.